# About the Sharkovsky Forcing Theorem

Tags: dynamical-systems

(Sharkovsky Forcing Theorem ). If $m$ is a period for $f$ and $m⊲ l$ , then $l$ is also a period for $f$. I have the following question:

Let $f$ be a such map having a period three, So $f$ is chaotic. But for some initial conditions $f$ tending to infinity. How I can guarantee the existence of other all periods for f in this case?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your concerns? For example, is there something specific about the proof of Sharkovsky's Theorem that you have doubts about in this case?

Comment: @LeeMosher: I have read several proofs. They do not use initial conditions. But I have some doubts that they assume that the solution is bounded (altghout this is not indicated in any reference). See: http://www.tufts.edu/as/math/Preprints/BurnsHasselblattShort.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see from the first few lines of the link you provided that the domain of $f$ can be any interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$, without any assumption that $I$ is closed or bounded. All that is required is that $f : I \to I$ be continuous, in particular there is no assumption anywhere saying that each orbit $x, f(x), f^2(x), f^3(x),\ldots$ is bounded.

So yes, given an initial condition $x$ the orbit $x, f(x), f^2(x), f^3(x),\ldots$ is allowed to be unbounded, to tend to infinity, etc.

The only hypothesis (beyond continuity) is that there **exists** a period 3 orbit, and the conclusion is that for each $l$ there **exists** a period $l$ orbit.